# Distribution function of a Bernoulli variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. real-valued random variables. Let $F_X$ be the (common) distribution function of these random variables.

> 1. Find the distribution function of the random variable
>    $Y=\max\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ in terms of $F_X$.

We have $F_Y(x)=\mathbb{P}(Y\le x)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x,\dots,X_n\le x)\overset{X_i\, i.i.d.}=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x)\cdot\cdot\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_n\le x)=F_X(x)^n$

> 2. In case when the $X_i$’s are Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$, that is $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 0) = p$, $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = 1 − p$, find the expectation of $Y$ .

My approach: Is it right to say, since $\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=1-p$, that $F_X(0)=\mathbb{P}(X\le0)=p$, $F_X(1)=\mathbb{P}(X\le1)=p(1-p)?$ I don't know, it starts getting confusing. Maybe this is not relevant for the exercise?

$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}k\mathbb{P}(Y=k)$? Since Bernoulli distribution is discrete. Any help?

Comment: For 2, $Y$ can only take the values $0$ or $1$.  What is the probability it is $1$ (use answer to 1)?  What is the expectation of $Y$?

Comment: @Henry since $Y$ is defined as the maximum of all $X_i$, does it mean that $F_Y(x)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)^n=(1-p)^n$?

Comment: No - clearly $P(Y\le 1)=F_Y(1)=1$.  But the interesting calculation is $P(Y=1)=P(Y\le 1)-P(Y\lt 1)$ which here is $F_Y(1)-F_Y(0) =1 - p^n$

Answer (score 1):

A full form of a Bernoulli cdf is
$$F_X(1)=1,\,F_X(0)=1-p\implies F_X(x)=(1-p)^{(1-\lfloor x\rfloor)^+}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)$$
Therefore
$$F_Y(x)=(F_X(x))^n=(1-p)^{n(1-\lfloor x\rfloor)^+}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)$$
This means that
$$P_Y(0)=(1-p)^n,\,P_Y(1)=1-(1-p)^n$$
and therefore $E[Y]=1-(1-p)^n$.

Comment: (note I use $P(X=0)=1-p$)